# There is only one linear function whose image of a specific base is a specific set of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

So I found this theorem:

*Let $V$ be a real vector space of dimension $n$, and $\mathscr{B} = \{\mathbf{b}_1, \dotsc, \mathbf{b}n\}$ its base;  let $V'$ be a real vector space and $\mathbf{c}_1, \dotsc, \mathbf{c}_n$ elements of $V'$. There exists only one linear function $f : V \rightarrow V'$ that satisfies $\forall i \in \{1, \dotsc, n\} \quad f(\mathbf{b}_i) = \mathbf{c}_i$.*

*Proof: Let $\mathbf{v \in V}$ satisfy $\mathbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \mathbf{b}_i$. We can define $f$ as $f(\mathbf{v}) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i\mathbf{c}_i$. It's easily proven that $f$ is a linear function and that $f(\mathbf{b}_i) = \mathbf{c_i}$. Now let $g: V \rightarrow V'$ another linear function that satisfies $\forall i \ g(\mathbf{b}_i) = \mathbf{c}_i$. Then
$$g(\mathbf{v}) = g \left( \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \mathbf{b}_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_ig(\mathbf{b}_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i\mathbf{c}_i = f(\mathbf{v})$$
proves the unicity of $f$.*

This is all clear, but there was a note saying that *"if $\mathscr{B}$ isn't a base of $V$, but just linearly independent, then $f$ exists but isn't unique; if $\mathscr{B}$ is not a base but a system of generators of $V$, then $f$ cannot exist."* without further explanation.

Isn't it the other way around? If $\mathscr{B}$ is linearly indepentent but not a base, $\mathbf{v}$ may not satisfy $\mathbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \mathbf{b}_i$; similarly, if $\mathscr{B}$ is a linearly dependent system of generators, $\mathbf{v}$ can be expressed as the linear combination of $\mathscr{B}$ in multiple ways. Would that be a typo?

*Note: the theorem was originally in Italian, I apologise for any mistranslation.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements are indeed the right way around. Think of it this way: if I try to assume too much about $f$, I will likely break linearity; we have already determined what a basis will go to, so everything else in the image must be a linear combination of things in the image of the basis.

Similarly, if we haven't assumed all that we possibly could about $f$, then we *do* have the freedom to 1) extend $\mathscr{B}$ to a basis (which is always possible), and then 2) send the rest of this basis to anything we like.